# PHP - merge only keys of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have a PHP array:

```
$array1 = array(
   'protein' => array('PROT', 100, 150),
   'fat'     => array('FAT',  100, 250),
   'carbs'   => arary('CARBS', 10, 20)
);

$array2 = array(
   'vitaminA' => array('vitA', 1, 2),
   'vitaminB' => array('vitB', 1, 2),
   'vitaminC' => arary('vitC', 1, 2)
);
```

Now I want a combined array of those nutrients (something like `array_merge()`), but I only need the keys, not the values themselves.

So either this:

```
$combined = array(
   'protein' => NULL,
   'fat'     => NULL,
   'carbs'   => NULL,
   'vitaminA'=> NULL,
   'vitaminB'=> NULL,
   'vitaminC'=> NULL
);
```

OR

```
$combined = array('protein', 'fat', 'carbs', 'vitaminA', 'vitaminB', 'vitaminC');
```

I can do this manually with a `foreach` loop, but I was hoping there's a function which would make this process fast and optimized.

Comment: `array_merge(array_keys($array1),array_keys($array2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't this do the trick?

```
$combined = array_merge(array_keys($array1), array_keys($array2));
```

This would result in your *option #2*.

I haven't done any benchmarks but I know that `isset()` is faster than `in_array()` in many cases; something tells me that it will be the same for `isset()` versus `array_key_exists()`. If it matters that much, you could try to use this:

```
$combined = array_flip(array_merge(array_keys($array1), array_keys($array2)));
```

Which would result in something like this:

```
$combined = array(
    'protein' => 1,
    'fat'     => 2,
    'carbs'   => 3,
    'vitaminA'=> 4,
    'vitaminB'=> 5,
    'vitaminC'=> 6
);
```

That would allow you to use `isset()`, e.g. *option #1*.

**#edit** I did some research on the performance of all three mentioned functions and most, if not all, case studies show that `isset()` is the fastest of all ([1](http://ilia.ws/archives/247-Performance-Analysis-of-isset-vs-array_key_exists.html), [2](http://blog.straylightrun.net/2008/12/03/tip-of-the-day-codeissetcode-vs-codein_arraycode/)); mainly because it is not actually a function but a language construct.

However do note that we now use `array_flip()` to be able to use `isset()`, so we lose quite a few microseconds to flip the array; therefore the total execution time is only decreasing if (and only if) you use `isset()` quite often.

Comment: I'm wondering which is better -- keep them as keys (option 1) or values (option 2)? Which would be faster -- checking with isset(), or checking with array_key_exists(), or checking with in_array() ?

Comment: @RichardRodriguez does performance matter that much in your app? we're talking minuscule differences here

Comment: I'm not sure if the performance you gain by being able to use `isset()` is going to be enough to offset the use of `array_flip()`, but you can give it a shot. Both _option #1_ and _option #2_ can be created by simple PHP-functions.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
function array_merge_keys($arr1, $arr2) {
    return array_merge(array_keys($arr1), array_keys($arr2));
}
```

should do the trick.